# point from n3290 :alignment

Tags: c++, alignment, c++11

A point from ISO standard n3290 draft ,Section 3.11:Alignment : 1st point

> Object types have alignment requirements (3.9.1, 3.9.2) which place restrictions on 
>       the addresses at which an object of that type may be allocated. An alignment is an
>       implementation-defined integer value representing the number of bytes between 
>       successive addresses at which a given object can be allocated.An object type imposes
>       an alignment requirement on every object of that type; stricter alignment can be     requested using the alignment specifier (7.6.2).

can any one please explain the above point  with an example ?

Comment: Seems like a pretty good explanation to me. Maybe you should explain what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, something like [Wikipedia's article on alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)?